# Add axis ticks to ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my code :

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=x,y=y))
geom_point(size=5) 
stat_smooth(method='glm', se = FALSE)
scale_y_log10()+ xlab("time")
ylab(expression(log(z^2))) 
scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(dat$y), max(dat$y), by = 10),1))
```

In the last line I wand to add ticks on y axis, but I have an error 
Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing `scale_y_log10()`, so adding `scale_y_continuous()` doesn't make sense. Instead make the breaks inside `scale_y_log10()`:

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=x,y=y)) +
geom_point(size=5) +
stat_smooth(method='glm', se = FALSE) +
scale_y_log10(breaks = round(seq(min(dat$y), max(dat$y), by = 10),1))+ xlab("time") +
ylab(expression(log(z^2)))
```

should work, although when you don't post a minimal example, it's hard to be sure.